# How to make user inputted data automatically appear on a new line?

Tags: python

this is the first time I've used this website, and am hoping someone here can help me out. One of my class assignments (intro to programming and we're using python) was to "Create a function that allows the user to write and create a text file. Create 5 lines of text for the newly created text file." (there's more to it, but this is the part that was giving me trouble). I have solved it another way, however I would really like to have the code I started with work out as it allows the user (in theory) to enter anything they want. My code is as follows:

```
def main():
filename = input("What is the name of this file: ")
target = open(filename, "w")
count = 0
while count != 5:
    count = count + 1
    infile = input("Enter something to be written to your file: ")
    target.write(infile)
if count == 5:
    target.close()
    print("Text has been added to the file.")
```

This code works to the extent that a user is able to enter what they want, however obviously everything being written to the text file is added one after another. So it turns out as a giant block of characters, and I can't figure out how to make it appear on another line.

For example:

Enter something to be written to your file: These

Enter something to be written to your file: Are

Enter something to be written to your file: Five

Enter something to be written to your file: Different

Enter something to be written to your file: Lines.

Which comes out as: TheseAreFiveDifferentLines. I know that part of the problem is that the loop I have is telling the program to write each input to the file one after the other, but how do I make it so that each input comes out as its' own line? I tried using end="", however I could not figure out where to put that without receiving a syntax error back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add [newline characters ("\n")](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
target.write("%s\n" % infile)
```